# Dockerfile: scope of ARG

Tags: docker

the Docker documentation says that

> An `ARG` instruction goes out of scope at the end of the build stage where it was defined. To use an argument in multiple stages, each stage must include the ARG instruction.

However, my experience is that ARG does not go out of scope.
Consider the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04 AS ubuntu-base
ARG TEST_ARG=hello
RUN echo $TEST_ARG

FROM ubuntu-base AS my-image
RUN echo $TEST_ARG
```

When building it I see

```
 => [ubuntu-base 2/2] RUN echo hello
 => [my-image 1/1] RUN echo hello
```

As you can see, both build-stages are able to access the `ARG` even without re-declaring it.
I get the same behavior if I indicate a value for the arg when building (e.g. `--build-arg TEST_ARG=world`).

Why is that?
Is that just an "implementation detail" and I shouldn't rely for it to work this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that since you are re-using the image from the first stage for the second stage, the ARGs that were defined in that image get carried into any following stages it's used for.

Here is an example Dockerfile that clarifies what is happening:

```
FROM busybox AS first
ARG FIRST
RUN echo "1st $FIRST"

FROM busybox AS second
ARG SECOND
RUN echo "2nd $SECOND"
RUN touch /test

FROM first AS third
COPY --from=second /test /test 
RUN echo "3rd first:$FIRST second:$SECOND"
```

Build the Dockerfile with:

```
docker build --no-cache --build-arg FIRST=one --build-arg SECOND=two .
```

You'll notice the following in the output:

```
[first 2/3] RUN echo "1st one"
[second 2/2] RUN echo "2nd two"
[third 2/2] RUN echo "3rd first:one second:$SECOND"
```

**Since the first image was re-used for the third stage, it prints the ARG that was passed to the first stage. But the ARG from the second stage is not printed**.

The documentation is technically wrong and should probably be expanded to say that ARGs used in a stage are passed to any stages that re-use the image from that stage.

This behavior is discussed in this Github issue:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37345#issuecomment-400250849

thaJeztah's following comment does not mention anything about not being able to rely on this behavior, so I assume you could rely on it. But there is no concrete answer to whether it's just an "implementation detail". I suppose you would have to ask them in a Github issue.

- small note about `touch /test`, that was only added to force buildkit to run the second stage. if the final stage does not use anything from a previous stage, that previous stage is not run.